# PostgreSQL using data from multiple joins to query data from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables I want to use for 1 SQL query.

```
customers:
 - id
 - first_name
 - last_name

customer_professional:
 - id
 - customer_id
 - professional_id

company_customer:
 - id
 - customer_id
 - company_id
```

The query I'm trying to run is to grab all the customers where the `professional_id = ?` and the `company_id = ?`. This is the query I've come with it so far.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers c 
       INNER JOIN customer_professional cp 
               ON c.id = cp.customer_id 
       INNER JOIN company_customer cc 
               ON c.id = cc.customer_id 
WHERE  ( cp.professional_id = '36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381bab' ) 
        OR ( cc.company_id = '36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381baa' ) 
ORDER  BY "first_name" 
LIMIT  50;
```

This query is returning only the customers that are in both the `customer_professional` and `company_customer`. The query I'm trying to run should return all customers even if they are only in 1 of the junction tables.

**SIDE NOTE**:

I know what you're thinking this should only be 2 tables. I agree with you.

**UPDATE**

Data I'm expecting:

```
customers table:
|  id  |  first_name  |  last_name  |
-------------------------------------
|  1   |  peter       |  griffin    |
|  2   |  meg         |  griffin    |
|  3   |  stewie      |  griffin    |
|  4   |  louis       |  griffin    |
|  5   |  bryan       |  griffin    |

customer_professional table:
|  id  |  customer_id  |  professional_id  |
--------------------------------------------
|  1   |  1            |  1                |
|  2   |  2            |  1                |
|  3   |  5            |  1                |

company_customer table:
|  id  |  customer_id  |  company_id  |
---------------------------------------
|  1   |  3            |  2           |
|  2   |  4            |  2           |
|  3   |  5            |  2           |
```

So with the query I want to run I have the `company_id` and the `professional_id` and I want to return the customers that belong to either a professional or the company.

query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customers c 
       INNER JOIN customer_professional cp 
               ON c.id = cp.customer_id 
       INNER JOIN company_customer cc 
               ON c.id = cc.customer_id 
WHERE  ( cp.professional_id = '1 ) 
        OR ( cc.company_id = 2 ) 
ORDER  BY "first_name" 
LIMIT  50;
```

This only returns:

```
|  id  |  first_name  |  last_name  |
-------------------------------------
|  5   |  bryan       |  griffin    |
```

The query I'm trying to run should return

```
|  id  |  first_name  |  last_name  |
-------------------------------------
|  1   |  peter       |  griffin    |
|  2   |  meg         |  griffin    |
|  3   |  stewie      |  griffin    |
|  4   |  louis       |  griffin    |
|  5   |  bryan       |  griffin    |
```

Comment: What's the result you're expecting? Please add the fields you want as a result.

Comment: @Dan I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need `left join` instead of `inner join`

Answer (score 1):

This is what [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) does: it keeps only the intersection between the tables. That is only the entries that appear in both. I think what you are after is `left join` which keeps all the entries which allows you to filter them using the `where` clause.

Comment: Alan answered the question right before. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM customers c INNER JOIN
     customer_professional cp 
     ON c.id = cp.customer_id AND
        cp.professional_id = '36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381bab' INNER JOIN
     company_customer cc 
     ON c.id = cc.customer_id AND
        cc.company_id = '36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381baa' 
WHERE cp.customer_id IS NOT NULL OR cc.customer_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER  BY "first_name" 
LIMIT  50;
```

First, I find your question confusing.  The text says "and", but you appear to want "or".  Second, the two additional tables are *junction* tables, not *pivot* tables.

The changes are:

- This only selects columns from the `customers` table.  I'm not sure that you really need the other columns.
- The conditions on the ids are moved to `ON` clauses.
- The joins are changed to `LEFT JOIN`s.
- The `WHERE` clause checks that there is at least one match.

Comment: This only returns customers that are in both junction tables.

Comment: @Rodrigo . . . It should return customers that are in *either* junction table.  That is why the `WHERE` clause has an `OR`.